# Google Cloud Integration with Standalone Struts2 Web application framework

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to integrate the google cloud with existing struts2 web application which is deployed locally to our server. Can you please advise how to go about this?

I am only finding samples where it talks about integrating with the application deployed in google cloud.

Comment: I am able to integrate the good cloud from standalone java application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
Authentication Code

package com.biperf.fsr.core.googlecloud;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Collections;

import com.biperf.fsr.ui.upload.StorageServiceAccountSample;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

public class GoogleCloudAuthentication
{  

  /** Global configuration of Google Cloud Storage OAuth 2.0 scope. */
  private static final String STORAGE_SCOPE =
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write";

  private static Storage client;

  /** Authorizes the web application to access the cloud data. */
  public Storage authorize(HttpTransport httpTransport, String serviceAccountEmail, String bucketName, JsonFactory jsonFactory, String applicationName ) throws Exception {

    // Check for valid setup
    Preconditions.checkArgument(!serviceAccountEmail.startsWith("[["),
        "Please enter your service account e-mail from the Google APIs "
        + "Console to the SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL constant in %s",
        GoogleCloudAuthentication.class.getName());
    Preconditions.checkArgument(!bucketName.startsWith("[["),
        "Please enter your desired Google Cloud Storage bucket name "
        + "to the BUCKET_NAME constant in %s", StorageServiceAccountSample.class.getName());
    String p12Content = Files.readFirstLine(new File("key.p12"), Charset.defaultCharset());
    Preconditions.checkArgument(!p12Content.startsWith("Please"), p12Content);

    // Build service account credential.
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(STORAGE_SCOPE))
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
        .build();

    // XML Response Set up and execute Google Cloud Storage request.
    /*String URI = "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName;    
    HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);        
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(URI);
    HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
    HttpResponse response = request.execute();
    String content = response.parseAsString();*/

    // JSON Response Set up global Storage instance.
    client = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(applicationName).build();

    //return content;
    return client;
  } 

Action Class

import com.biperf.fsr.core.googlecloud.GoogleCloudAuthentication;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Bucket;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class StorageServiceAccountSample {

  /** E-mail address of the service account. */
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

  /** Bucket to list. */
  private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "XXXXXX";

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        // Proxy Settings
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 8080));

        // Instance of the HTTP transport
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().setProxy(proxy).build();

        // Authorization.
        GoogleCloudAuthentication gca = new GoogleCloudAuthentication();      
        //String content = gca.authorize(httpTransport, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, BUCKET_NAME,  JSON_FACTORY, APPLICATION_NAME);
        Storage client = gca.authorize(httpTransport, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, BUCKET_NAME,  JSON_FACTORY, APPLICATION_NAME);

        // Instantiate transformer input
        /*Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(content));
        StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());

        // Configure transformer
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); // An identity
                                                                                     // transformer
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "testing.dtd");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);

        // Pretty print the output XML.
        System.out.println("\nBucket listing for " + BUCKET_NAME + ":\n");
        System.out.println(xmlOutput.getWriter().toString());*/
        //System.exit(0);

        // Get metadata about the specified bucket.
        Storage.Buckets.Get getBucket = client.buckets().get(BUCKET_NAME);
        getBucket.setProjection("full");
        Bucket bucket = getBucket.execute();
        System.out.println("name: " + BUCKET_NAME);
        System.out.println("location: " + bucket.getLocation());
        System.out.println("timeCreated: " + bucket.getTimeCreated());
        System.out.println("owner: " + bucket.getOwner());

        // List the contents of the bucket.
        Storage.Objects.List listObjects = client.objects().list(BUCKET_NAME);
        com.google.api.services.storage.model.Objects objects;
        do {
          objects = listObjects.execute();
          for (StorageObject object : objects.getItems()) {
            System.out.println("File Name: " + object.getName() + " (" + object.getSize() + " bytes)");
            System.out.println("File Link: " + object.getSelfLink());            
          }
          listObjects.setPageToken(objects.getNextPageToken());
        } while (null != objects.getNextPageToken());

      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }   
      System.exit(1);
  }
}
```